# How to test a wsdl webservice?

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl

i'm completely new to webservices (and especially with SOAP / WSDL)
Right now, i have a `.WSDL` in the root of my server which i have fully automatically generated.

**How to test that my webservice is functionning (echoing the right results) without bugs ?**
**How to interact with that .wsdl file ?**

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or use [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Comment: Delicious!  That's a test I can do all day long.

Comment: Oh Great! A link to a proprietary piece of software.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP, I would say you look into [PHP SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).